# Oracle XML Parsing - ORA-19202 and LPX-00601

Tags: oracle, xml-parsing

I am new to XML parsing in oracle, I am getting ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing and LPX-00601: Invalid token for below query. Can anyone please help ?

```
TABLENAME = PARSEXML 
COLUMN1('ID') = VARCHAR |COLUMN2('XML') = CLOB

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns4:TSTCLOB xmlns:ns4="http://example.org/test" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns4:Rqst>
        <ns2:Initiation>
            <ns2:InitiationDetail>
                <ns3:Channel>WEB</ns3:Channel>
                <ns3:Unit>ABCD</ns3:Unit>
            </ns2:InitiationDetail>
        </ns2:Initiation>
    </ns4:Rqst>
</ns4:TSTCLOB>

SELECT ID, EXTRACT(xmltype(XML), '\ns4:TSTCLOB\ns4:Rqst\ns2:Initiation\ns2:InitiationDetail\ns3:Unit') "unit"
FROM PARSEXML WHERE ID = '123'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your example xml is not valid. It is using 4 namespace but only 2 are declared.  You have to add this `xmlns:ns2="Namespace2"  xmlns:ns3="Namespace3"`

```
<ns4:TSTCLOB xmlns:ns4="http://example.org/test"   xmlns:ns2="Namespace2"  xmlns:ns3="Namespace3" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ns4:Rqst>
        <ns2:Initiation>
            <ns2:InitiationDetail>
                <ns3:Channel>WEB</ns3:Channel>
                <ns3:Unit>ABCD</ns3:Unit>
            </ns2:InitiationDetail>
        </ns2:Initiation>
    </ns4:Rqst>
</ns4:TSTCLOB>
```

2) In xpath you have to use slash instead of backslash `\` -> `/` = `'/ns4:TSTCLOB/ns4:Rqst/ns2:Initiation/ns2:InitiationDetail/ns3:Unit'`

3) Extract method has 3 parameters, the last one is namespace string. If your xml is using other namespace except default one you have to specify this in extract method.

```
Extract(xml, '/ns4:TSTCLOB/ns4:Rqst/ns2:Initiation/ns2:InitiationDetail/ns3:Unit','xmlns:ns4="http://example.org/test"   xmlns:ns2="Namespace2"  xmlns:ns3="Namespace3" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"')
```

4*) `Extract,ExtractValue` are deprecated , you should use `xmltable` or `xmlquery`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach (simplified the XML for testing purpose):

```
with tmp as(
select
  xmltype(to_clob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TSTCLOB>
      <Rqst>
        <Initiation>
          <InitiationDetail>
            <Channel>WEB</Channel>
            <Unit>ABCD</Unit>
          </InitiationDetail>
        </Initiation>
      </Rqst>
    </TSTCLOB>')) tmp_xml
  from dual)
select
  xml_tbl.Channel,
  xml_tbl.Unit
from
  tmp,
  xmltable(
   '/TSTCLOB/Rqst/Initiation/InitiationDetail' passing tmp.tmp_xml
    columns
      Channel varchar2(6) path 'Channel',
      Unit varchar2(6) path 'Unit') xml_tbl
```